# Run two Neo4j instances as Windows Service on one machine

Tags: neo4j, windows-services

I can start already two different Neo4j instances on my Windows machine on the console, but how can I now start them automatically as a Windows Service? I was just able to install one with the powershell scripts.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install Neo4j as a service, Neo4j takes the configuration `dbms.windows_service_name` as a service name.

So to install two Neo4j as a service, you need to change one.

I recommend you to uninstall all neo4j services, and then to reinstall them with ta diffrent name.